# CAShapeLayer Driving me bonkers

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I'm trying to rotate a CAShapeLayer arounds its centre point. I'm really confused over bounds, frames, anchors and centre points.

I have created a circular CAShape within a UIView and want to rotate it around its centre. I have only included some of the code.

Function to Create the Circle I wish to rotate:

```
func drawCompassImage(){

    //Compass Bezel Ring
    let baseCirclePath = UIBezierPath()

    baseCirclePath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.frame.width/2), y: CGFloat(self.frame.width/2)), radius: CGFloat(baseCircleRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI_2*3), clockwise: true)
    compassImage.path = baseCirclePath.CGPath
    compassImage.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor;
    compassImage.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    compassImage.lineDashPattern = [1.0,2.0]
    compassImage.lineWidth = 10.0
    self.layer.addSublayer(compassImage)

}
```

Function to create the red dot:

```
func drawCompassRedDot() {

    let compassBall = CAShapeLayer ()
    let compassBallPath = UIBezierPath ()
    let compassBallRadius :CGFloat = 5

    let xStart: Float  = Float(Float(baseCircleRadius) * cos(270 * Float(M_PI) / 180)) + Float(self.frame.width/2)
    let yStart: Float  = Float(Float(baseCircleRadius) * sin(270 * Float(M_PI) / 180)) + Float((self.frame.height/2)+0)
    compassBallPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xStart), y: CGFloat(yStart)), radius: compassBallRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI_2*3), clockwise: true)
    compassBall.path = compassBallPath.CGPath
    compassBall.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor;
    compassBall.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    compassBall.lineWidth = 1.0
    self.compassImage.addSublayer(compassBall)
}
```

Functions to rotate:

```
func animate(){

    compassImage.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(degree2radian(45), 0, 0, 1)

}

func degree2radian(a:CGFloat)->CGFloat {
    let b = CGFloat(M_PI) * a/180
    return b
}
```

My issue is whatever I try it always ends off-set:

[image]

The two circles should have the same centre.

Please help this is sending me bonkers...

Comment: Can you post a little more context for where these functions are called so that I and others can help you more? @duck1970

Comment: Hi I've added the full code from the Class

Answer (score 1):

I've worked it out. Need to add in the bounds and anchor point correctly:

```
compassImage.frame = bounds
compassImage.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

Therefore the code looks like this:

```
func drawCompassImage(){

    //Compass Bezel Ring
    let baseCirclePath = UIBezierPath()

    baseCirclePath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.frame.width/2), y: CGFloat(self.frame.width/2)), radius: CGFloat(baseCircleRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI_2*3), clockwise: true)
    compassImage.path = baseCirclePath.CGPath
    compassImage.frame = bounds
    compassImage.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    compassImage.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor;
    compassImage.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    compassImage.lineDashPattern = [1.0,2.0]
    compassImage.lineWidth = 10.0
    self.layer.addSublayer(compassImage)

}
```

Comment: Note that your baseCirclePath.addArcWithCenter() works not probably because the frame and the bounds are the same. The frame is the rect of the view expressed in the superview's coordinate system. So if your view would be rotated, this would most likely no longer work as expected. When computing frames and positions within a view or layer, always use the bounds, and do not assume that bounds.origin will be 0,0. This way, it will keep working, even when the outside world of your view will distort you in crazy ways.

Comment: Great thanks for the update. So would you recommend changing this line? -
    baseCirclePath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.frame.width/2), y: CGFloat(self.frame.width/2)), radius: CGFloat(baseCircleRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI_2*3), clockwise: true)
    compassImage.path = baseCirclePath.CGPath

Comment: Yes. The shapeLayer is positioned in its super layer / view. So you want to use the coordinate system of that layer/view. Inversely, of your view wanted to know the rect your layer occupies in that, it would ask for that layer's frame. Not sure if you have check it out already, but if not: check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html